# Getting access to GDrive as app-specific user

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working with Google Drive from an [application-specific account](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts). It would be great to be able to get access to the GDrive UI logged with this account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to access the Google Drive web user interface of a service account.